# Dynamics CRM exceeding its storage limit, but "Resources in use" say only 28% used

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

We have a dynamics CRM online instance into which we are uploading about 2.2 million records.

We have done this before (several times) for trial instances with no problem. Usually they take up about 50% of the 5GB storage limit.

Last night we started doing the import into a new CRM instance - one that is linked to a sharepoint and an active office 365 account.

About 75% of the imports got in, but now we have an error message that is also displayed in the system notifications section of CRM. The message is "Your organization, XXXX, has exceeded its storage limit...".

However, when I check on the "Resources in Use" page in CRM, it tells me that we have used only 28% of the 5GB limit.

Any ideas?

[image: Resources in Use screenshot]

[image: System Notification about storage limits being exceeded]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Support resolved this today.

Their response to me included:

"...The organization quote was unfortunately set incorrectly and the operations team have set it back to 5GB. The issue was on our side and was not caused by you or by importing the data..."

Answer (score 3):

There can be a difference between the actual and reported storage figures for a couple of reasons:

1. Your imports might trigger system jobs. System job records are often deleted later, but while they exist could consume a lot of storage which is then freed up once those jobs are deleted. It's possible that you are looking at the 'Resources in Use' page after the jobs have been deleted.
2. CRM Online's storage analysis is performed on a batch basis (but I'm not sure of the frequency). So there is often a delay between loading/deleting records and seeing the storage resource utilization change.

In either case, you will probably need to contact CRM Online Support to determine how best to address your issue.

Comment: I have raised a query with CRM online support and am awaiting a response.

On 30th Nov, I deleted 500,000 of the records that we had imported. the Resources in use actually went up to 31.6% after that and have stayed at that level since.

System Notification is still telling us that we have exceeded our limits and we can't create new records.

I have since imported the same records into another trial instance with no problems.